# How to create entity reference field from custom entity to another custom entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm on Drupal 8 and I created a custom entity `custom_entity_one` following the Drupal 8 examples, the `content_entity_example` module. 
Now, in another custom entity, `custom_entity_two` I'm trying to create a `BaseFieldDefinition` like so:

```
$fields['cid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('custom_entity_one ID'))
  ->setSettings(array(
    'target_type' => 'custom_entity_one',
    'multiple' => TRUE,
    'handler' => 'default'
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'id',
    'weight' => -1,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'settings' => array(
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => 60,
      'placeholder' => '',
    ),
    'weight' => -1,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

In the add form of the `custom_entity_two`, the reference field appears, however, it doesn't find any value, even though I have multiple entities of type `custom_entity_one`.

I thought that it will look for the `label` propriety of the entity, but it doesn't seem so. What I am missing ? Should I create a custom handler ? I'm not very sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I was right, right after I posted the question I checked if I'm missing the entity_key label, and I was. I added it in the entity annotation definition, like so:

```
entity_keys = {
  "id" = "id",
  "uuid" = "uuid",
  "label" = "title",
},
```

Comment: Yeah, see also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210610/why-doesnt-my-custom-entity-work-in-an-entity-reference-field, pretty much the same question.

Comment: @Berdir, yes, sorry for that, I couldn't find it on my first search, this question then may be deleted if it's not contributing to the community.

Comment: No worries. I just added that as a reference, has a bit more infos. drupal answers/stack exchange has no rule against asking duplicate questions, although they are sometimes closed as duplicate (but never deleted). having the same question asked in slightly different ways might allow more users to find it.